# Error while loading large amount of data in a tableviewcell

Tags: iphone

Ha ii everybody,i have a problem with my tableview cell,i am loading bible verses on the basis of chapter in a tableview,but unfortunately when the chapter psalms loaded the application freeze throwing an exeption that

```
done
2011-11-09 11:25:50.636 Bible[1556:207] CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).
```

there is no problem in loading all other chapters,i think this chapter has a huge amount of datas that means more than 150 chapter,how can i solve this problem.Anyone have any idea of solve my issue please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you please share the lines of code where you get this exception ? It is surely not a problem for large amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check out you array which you are using to feed the table view cells.
The problem may be due to index out of bound.
The index at which you are inserting or scrolling, the array doesn't have that.
So make break points,log your array there when you scroll the table.

`[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]`

You will find the answer for your problem then.

Cheers

Comment: but sir there is no problem when loding alla other chapters,can you xplain please.thanks

Comment: Brother first debug your program....And print your array or dictionary which you are using....And check that it contains any data at the time of your scrolling the table view.....If  your array data would be nil and you try to scroll to a position which doesn't exist,then your app will crash.....Put break point in your cellforrowatindex path as well and also show some other part of code where you are using this table related data in other methods,debug those as well......